# Hotspot on Windows 7 & Ubuntu without any third-party software

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hotspot

How can I make a hotspot using windows 7 without the use of any third-party software such as connectify? And how do I make hotspot on ubuntu without downloading any additional software?

Comment: I think that these two questions should be asked separately. What have you tried to do to make a hotspot? What version of Windows are you currently running? What hardware you have installed in your machine?

Comment: google "internet connection sharing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your question can be found pretty easily on google, here are two links that seems to suit your needs :

For ubuntu : http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/
For windows 7 : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21943/share-an-internet-connection-between-wireless-machines-with-an-ad-hoc-network-in-windows-7/